# Swift: Table Cells not setting up buttons correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I have been following a tutorial online for a yikyak clone using swift and parse. i am storing the objectIDs of the upvoted/downvoted items using coreData. When the tableview cell is loaded, it checks if the objectID on parse is in coreData and responds accordingly by adding a background image to the specific button and disabling both the up and down vote buttons. However, I am facing an issue where scrolling up and down a few times causes random cells to have the background and have their buttons disabled.

Here is a link to the code (cellForRowAtIndexPath:):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PullTableViewCell
    let restaurant = self.restaurantData[indexPath.row]
    cell.scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

    cell.plusButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.plusButton.addTarget(self, action: "plusOne:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.minusButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.minusButton.addTarget(self, action: "minusOne:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    if (cell.plusButton.enabled) {
        // upvotes
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Upvotes")
        let moc:NSManagedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext!

        var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
        self.upvoteData = moc.executeFetchRequest(request, error: error) as [Upvotes]

        for (var i = 0; i < self.upvoteData.count; i++) {
            if (self.upvoteData[i].objectid == self.objectIDs[indexPath.row]) {
                NSLog("the cell is in view is \(indexPath.row)")
                cell.plusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                cell.minusButton.enabled = false
                cell.plusButton.enabled = false
            }
        }

        // downvotes
        let request2 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Downvotes")
        let moc2:NSManagedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext!

        var error2: NSErrorPointer = nil
        self.downvoteData = moc2.executeFetchRequest(request2, error: error2) as [Downvotes]

        for (var i = 0; i < self.downvoteData.count; i++) {
            if (self.downvoteData[i].objectid == self.objectIDs[indexPath.row]) {
                cell.minusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                cell.minusButton.enabled = false
                cell.plusButton.enabled = false
            }
        }

    }
    return cell
}
```

Does it have to do with asynchronous processing?

Comment: You should paste your code inside the post instead of linking it. Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited it. I tried creating 2 new arrays called isUpvoted and isDownvoted and stored a true and false for each item. Then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: it would check if it is true. If it was true it would set the background to blue and the buttons would be disabled. (for both up and down voted). I still had the same problems.

Comment: So it actually creates new cells every time you scroll up or down (you can verify this yourself by checking the memory addresses). What you need to do is store all the properties you want each cell to have and assign them again in this method.

Answer (score 0):

The tableview actually re-creates cells on the fly as you scroll up and down. So when a cell is scrolled out of view it can get destroyed and re-created.

You need to store cell properties inside of a map and then re-initialize the cell each time.

Here is an example from my own code:

```
public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("selectPhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as B_SelectPhotoControllerViewCell
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        let asset = currentAssetAtIndex(indexPath.item)
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize:_cellSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil)
        {
            result, info in
            if(cell.indexPath == indexPath)
            {
                cell.imageView.image = result
                cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self._cellSize.width,self._cellSize.height)
                for editImage in self._editImageChicklets
                {
                    if(editImage.selectedPhotoIndexPath != nil && editImage.selectedPhotoIndexPath == indexPath)
                    {
                        cell.number = editImage.selectedPhotoDisplayNumber!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

This is an example of a UICollectionView that uses photo images from the users photo roll. I keep track of the indexPath, and if its a match, then I assign the images to the property.

In your case you need to do the same. Keep a map of the cell properties and the index path:

```
Dictionary<NSIndexPath,CustomCellPropertiesObject>
```

Then go through and re-initialize it appropriately.